# Laravel 4.2 - Accessing object properties

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to access all of a objects properties.

In my UsersController:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return View::make('users.edit')->with('user', User::find($id));
}
```

In users/edit view I can access only some of the objects properties such as `{{ $user->username }}` and `{{ $user->email }}` however, I cannot access `{{ $user->id }}` or `{{ $user->role_id }}` ... the app complains about trying to get the property of a non-object. On the other hand if I use `{{ dd($user->id) }}` it returns the correct value as expected. Being new to Laravel and Eloquent I'm at a loss for why this might be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the result if you run {{$user}} in your view ?

Comment: Have to use `{{ die($user) }}` and the result of that is a normal json-like object containing all the data of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try change variable name user to something else. Some frameworks has $user variable reserved in they templating system.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. I suppose it might help to add that I use the same controller and view setup for UsersController show and have no problems accessing the data.

Comment: Can you show up view code? And response from die($user)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns that I inadvertently overwrote the `$user` object which resulted in having access to only some of the object attributes. The non-object error made sense considering the second `$user` was no long the user object returned from the controller. It was a silly mistake and I feel foolish for overlooking it in the first place. Thank you everyone for the input!